# Power BI Can't create relationship between two tables

Tags: powerbi

I have tables like this diagram, and existing relationships are in highlighted boxes.

[image]

Then I tried to create relationship between Dates[Date] and Users[Last Hire Date], I got an error message saying there is an ambiguous conflict.

[image]I don't see what conflict there is and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ambiguity is easier to see when you start with the Dates table. The arrows in the relations represent the filter direction. By selecting a certein Date in Dates, you are selecting several Emails in Time Log Aggregation where Date of Worklog equals Date. Simultaneously you are selecting several other Emails in Useres and Groups, where Last Hire Date equals Date. These 2 selections of Emails have nothing in common and they would match only by pure coincidence.

A workaround for this situation would be to duplicate the Dates table.